# How do I install NVIDIA drivers on Ubunu 14.04 Kernel 3.13 running on Zynq SoC?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I've been trying to install various versions of the NVIDIA driver (for a GTX 980) connected to a board that has a Xilinx Zynq SoC on it. The SoC has dual ARM9 cores which are running Ubuntu 14.04 with Kernel Version 3.13 (which is not the mainline because Xilinx's kernel provides drivers for its IP on its official version of the Linux Kernel: https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx).

I have been running into issues I am not quite sure how to resolve - hence, reaching out to the wider community to get help with pointers / solutions.

I have posted my query on NVIDIA's developer forum as well which is here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/924700/linux/nvidia-driver-installation-on-xilinx-zynq-soc-running-ubuntu-14-04-kernel-3-13-/

Any ideas on what could be missing or not configured properly?

I should note that this embedded OS is not supposed to have a desktop environment and the GPU is to be used for computational purposes only. Hence, the desktop is not installed on the filesystem.